# Are the computers out to get me?

Tags: mario-kart-double-dash

I was at my friends house, and we were trying to beat the Special Cup on Mirror Mode (to unlock the Boo Pipes). After awhile, we noticed that the computer players would tend to target us over the other computer players. Are they designed to target the human player(s) in this mode, or were we just getting unlucky?

I started to assume the computers were targeting us when one of them back threw a Red Shell (hitting me) despite him being in 3rd, me in 4th, and 2nd in the perfect spot to be hit.

Comment: My guess is that you're just noticing them attack you more. You don't get much visibility into computer players attacking each other, so it'll seem like they're attacking you the most, whether they are or not. As for your example, the AI may prioritize hitting human players, or it may prioritize hitting whoever has the highest overall score so far, or it may have just decided to hit you because you were the nearest target, even though you were behind.

Comment: Interesting reading (warning, this is a tvtropes link): http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GangUpOnTheHuman

Comment: I wonder this every game I play.

Comment: Here is the reason, WELCOME TO MARIO KART!